# Emitting Light from Object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, shaders, transparency

I'm trying to create a semi-transparent wrapper around a light source. This could be gems, brightly lit console buttons, magical semi-transparent glowing fruits, whatever.

Anywho, I tried the approach outlined in [another Stack Exchange question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24886/how-do-i-emit-light-from-inside-a-object) (transparent BSDF wrapped around an emission source), but the effect looks quite different from theirs. See the image below. I noticed in their example .blend file there was a field labeled "normal" applied to the transparent shader node that doesn't show up on mine. Is there a step I missed?

[image: Glowing Button WRONG]

It should look like this:

[image: Glowing Button]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I emit light from inside a object?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24886/how-do-i-emit-light-from-inside-a-object)

Comment: Partially, but I'm also curious about the normal attribute on the transparent shader, that doesn't appear as on option for me at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The post you linked to is using a *translucent* shader, you are using a *transparent* shader.

---

### Transparency vs. Translucency

Transparency simply lets light pass through the object, only changing the color and intensity.  Translucency lets the light through as well, but it scatters the light on the opposite side from which it struck the surface.

[image]

Translucency and transparency are the two basic types of transmission, they are akin to diffuse and glossy in terms of reflection.

Comment: Ahhhh, I feel dumb now. I looked at this for a solid 45 minutes trying to figure it out. Thanks a lot! :)