# Button emitting light in Eevee?

Tags: materials, shaders, light, eevee-render-engine

I’m trying to create a material for a button on a music control panel. It looks like a plastic glossy button with some colourful light coming from behind.

I’m using EEVEE engine, so I tried bumping the transmission to 100% and also checking the refraction in the render settings, but it’s not the best looking button, it seems not transparent.

[image]

**Q:** How to create a realistic looking shader for that plastic knob using eevee?

Comment: Related or dupe: [How do I emit light from inside a object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24886/how-do-i-emit-light-from-inside-a-object)

Comment: @brockmann Probably related, though this one's specifically for Eevee. So limited translucency, light diffusion, sss doesn't work, and no object thickness :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two ways that seem to work

1. Glass Shader with a Mesh light inside

   - enable *Screen Space Refraction* (in render tab and material setting)
   - set refraction depth to a non-zero number (to fake the glass thickness)
   - I used a *musgrave texture* to fake uneven light intensity
2. *Translucent BSDF* shader, with a *Point light* inside.

   - nicely simulates different thickness and light intensity
   - just keep in mind, that Eevee is limited to 128 lights per scene

*Glass button with a Mesh light inside*
[image]

*Translucent button with a  Point light inside*
[image]

Comment: Hi Jackym.

That's what I was trying to achieve, I was making a button transparent to give it reflections, and then adding a small mesh with emission within the glass button so it can emit light, But once I place the emission mesh in the glass, nothing is happening. I thought that the transparent object would be 100% like glass. Would it be possible instead of sun light, to have emission? Mostly I'm asking from technical aspect, although your answer is 100% correct and does magic in my scene!

Kind regards.

Comment: Hey :). I couldn't make it work at first, but now it seems to work. I updated the answer.

Comment: Great stuff, thank you!

Comment: Happy to help. Learned some new stuff too :).