# How do I make a crystal glow?

Tags: light, transparency, emission

[image]

I am trying to make the infinity stones and I am struggling to make them glow.

[This answers doesn't translate to my issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24886) since the solution involves creating a duplicate of the object scaling down and making it emit light. This ruins the transmission shading of the original object.

In  the films they emit a strong light from their cores. I want to animate them spinning in a circle so the glowing effect must be done in blender. I am currently using an hdr to light them. (using a gtx 960m chip so the less taxing the better).

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Light inside the cristals? Emission shader as materials of the objects? Outside light pointing to crystals (with very small radius to act light a laser)?

Comment: I put a point light inside the crystals which didnt work. I used the emission shader as materials of the objects aswell. Using an outside light might work if they were static but the end goal is to have them spinning

Answer (score -1):

Make a uv sphere inside the crystal , use emission shader , increase the strength of emission and render using evee.

Comment: I'm wanting to use cycles since the transparency is much more realistic