# How to do a neon light effect inside an object or be seen that way with blender 2.8?

Tags: node-editor, light, emission

I have this scene in Blender where I am trying to have neon lights emit through an object. See the lights inside the object seeping through?

[image]

But i'm not sure if that is possible since the object I am trying to do it on already has a texture and an emission nodes.

[image]

I'm wondering if there is another way to make it appear like the first image.

My idea:
I thought of making a emission mask just for those spots within the sign and fixing the orginal emission layer in photoshop.

What do you think?

Comment: You can use multiply node to 'add' the new emission to the original emission texture

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24886

Comment: Are they actual lights, other objects with emissions, or just an image?

Answer (score 1):

You can use another texture to mix color with your emission texture map:

[image]

See the Checker texture "Add" to the emission socket, make it light up as the checker go white. That node is **Color**→**MixRGB** in node editor.

Photoshop is another approach if you only want a quick prototype and keep thing simple.